# How do I share handlers between threads?

Tags: multithreading, rust

I am writing a multithreaded webserver and basically I need to copy a `Vec<Handler>` of user-provided handler objects across multiple threads on server startup. I tried several approaches:

1) Define Handler as a trait with a `fn process(&mut self, Request) -> Response` method. Users would implement it for each handler struct. This approach is very common in languages like C++ or python. The problem is that rust doesn't allow me to copy or clone a trait object as it would imply the `Sized` bound on it which is forbidden on trait objects.

2) Define Handler as a `Box<FnMut(Request) -> Response>`. This doesn't work as closures are not copyable.

3) I could share the same objects between threads but this makes very little sense to me as I would need a mutex which would introduce useless contention when I actually just need separate copies across threads.

How can I implement this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to request the user to define a clone method.

```
trait Handler {
    fn process(&mut self, r: Request) -> Response;
    fn duplicate(&self) -> Box<Handler>;
}
```

And then you can copy your `Vec<Box<Handler>>` quite easily.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it seems to not work well with threads. A given thread owns Box<Handler> but not Handler which implies Handler needs to implement Send. Rust can't figure out that the Handler object doesn't have references outside of the thread. This forces me to make Handler thread safe.

Comment: Copying and thread-safety are different issues, indeed if you wish to send the handler across threads you need either add the `Send` bound to `Handler` (and probably the `'static` bound as well) or you can add them to the Box as in `Box<Handler + Send + 'static>`. I would recommend the former, for convenience.

Comment: Naming that method `clone` would probably be confusing here.

Comment: @mcarton: How does `duplicate` sounds?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Less confusing :)

Comment: Having a method that's essentially `clone()` but belongs to another trait and has different name is still confusing. Why can't you just add `Clone` bound or derive `Handler` from `Clone` instead of creating new method?

Comment: @PavelStrakhov: Ah... that's a tricky one. `Clone` is not object safe, so it cannot be used virtually. Note here that I do not return `Handler` but `Box<Handler>` to make the method object safe.

Comment: @MatthieuM I understand your point about thread safety but why is it needed here? The point is to clone the handlers so that thread safety is not a worry anymore. This is what I mention in 3) of my original question.

Comment: @ElefEnt: I think that you are misunderstanding what `Send` and `Sync` are about => https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html ; in short `Send` means "I hold nothing that would be unsafe to be shared, so you can send me safely to another thread" whereas `Sync` means "I can be shared across threads safely". Thus, it makes sense to require that your handlers be `Send` if they will be sent to other threads.

Comment: @MatthieuM while I am at it, is there a solution with FnMut at all?

Comment: @ElefEnt: With sharing, yes, with cloning no (you cannot modify it to be clone friendly). Sharing would involve something such as `Arc<Mutex<FnMut(...) -> ...>>` and would require locking the whole handler during processing. Note that you may be able to send them across threads without cloning them (for example by assigning two handlers to one thread and two to another thread, or one handler per thread, ...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125020/discussion-between-matthieu-m-and-elefent).